# Чтение dat файла

Tags: python, pandas

Прочесть файл .dat (https://github.com/catauggie/first-expirience/blob/master/0_5.dat) питон смог, но как-то все слиплось в одну строчку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавление в строчку sep='' тоже не спасло ситуацию.
Подскажите, как можно исправить?

Comment: Что-то типа sep=' ' (пробел, а не пустая строка, как у вас) и кажется skip_rows=1 или как там сказать, что названия столбцов не в первой строке идут, а надо одну строку пропустить. Прочитайте описание функции read_csv, которой собственно и нужно читать ваш файл

Comment: Хотя я попробовал, что-то у меня тогда на другие строки вашего файла ругается, и `skiprows` надо писать без пробелов, у меня нет возможности сейчас проверить, может вы сами или кто-то другой нормально докопается )  Пробелов у вас местами много, тогда нужно использовать `sep=r'\s+'`.

Comment: я использовал read_csv, удалял вручную первую строку, но меня вот это удивило: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2919 entries, 0 to 2918
Data columns (total 7 columns):
 #   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------      --------------  -----  
 0   Wave        2919 non-null   float64
 1   Wawenumber  2919 non-null   float64
 2   Graph1      2919 non-null   object 
 3   Graph2      2919 non-null   object 
 4   Graph3      2919 non-null   object 
 5   Graph4      2919 non-null   object 
 6   Graph5      2619 non-null   object 
dtypes: float64(2), object(5)

Comment: т.е. из 2919 строк для последней колонки  Graph5 2619 non-null, хотя везде стоят float64 числа

Comment: Надо смотреть где `NA` получились, в каких строках, что у вас там в файле в этих местах. Может там запятая вместо точки или ещё какие-то сложности, надо смотреть, разбираться.